# Getting 'Key Error: "['None'] not in index

Tags: python, filtering

I am trying to find the distinct unique values in a column from my data frame.

```
df[ClientType].unique()
```

The result is throwing this error : `'Key Error: "['None'] not in index`

I created that column using

```
name_types = client_new.pivot_table(index='Name', values='AccountType', aggfunc=set) 
client_new['ClientType'] = client_new['Name'].apply(lambda x: name_types.loc[x]['AccountType'])
```

It's been a while since I have used Python and looking for some help to refresh. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps `ClientType` is `None`

Comment: Please show how `df` is defined as a [mcve]

Comment: I created that column using 

name_types = client_new.pivot_table(index='Name', values='AccountType', aggfunc=set)

client_new['ClientType'] = client_new['Name'].apply(lambda x: name_types.loc[x]['AccountType'])

Comment: So, did you mean `df["ClientType"]`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: `df` is almost certainly a pandas dataframe, although that detail should have been mentioned by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `ClientType` as a string like this

```
df['ClientType'].unique()
```